# undefined node js return value

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get my node js to return and output the value taken from a Html form.

The node.js file is as follows

```
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/myform', function(req, res) {
var myText = req.query.mytext; 
   res.send('Your Text:' +myText);
   fs.writeFile('app.py',myText,function(err) {
       if(err) throw err;
    });
});

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000!'));
```

The HTML is

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <body>
  <h1 style="color:Blue">Docker</h1>

   <div id="floating-panel">
       <form action="/myform" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="mytext" required />
           <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I fill out the form I get the Output "Your Text:undefined" , why isnt myText variable being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

req.query.mytext is wrong.
req.query use when you want to extract query string.
I think here you need to use req. body, Please replace your code with following code

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/myform', function(req, res) {
   const myText = req.body.mytext; 
   res.send('Your Text:' +myText);
   fs.writeFile('app.py',myText,function(err) {
      if(err) throw err;
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000!'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:
**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/myform', function(req, res) {
   var myText = req.body.mytext; 
   res.send('Your Text:' +myText);
   fs.writeFile('app.py',myText,function(err) {
       if(err) throw err;
    });
});

 app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening on port 3000!'));
```